# NullReferenceException on Entity Framework constructor

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, nullreferenceexception

I have a `DER.edmx`, and in `DER.Designer.cs` there is this autogenerated code

```
public SiGMAEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "SiGMAEntities")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

the line that throws the exception is

```
public SiGMAEntities(string connectionString) : base(connectionString, "SiGMAEntities")
```

A couple of days ago, everything worked perfectly but I had to re-install Windows for other reasons, and of course VS and SQL Server. The exception happened when I wanted to start working on the project again.

Stack trace

```
    [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.System.Collections.IDictionary.Remove(Object key) +48
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.RegisterDefaultObjectMappingItemCollection() +95
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace, Boolean required) +124
   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetItemCollection(DataSpace dataSpace) +48
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor) +438
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString) +65
   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName) +37
   AccesoADatos.SiGMAEntities..ctor(String connectionString) in E:\Documentos(NO BORRAR)\Documentos de GonDC\Facu\SiGMA\asd - Copy\trunk\AccesoADatos\DER.Designer.cs:79
   AccesoADatos.Conexion.crearSegunServidor() in E:\Documentos(NO BORRAR)\Documentos de GonDC\Facu\SiGMA\asd - Copy\trunk\AccesoADatos\Conexion.cs:27
   AccesoADatos.Datos.TiposDNI() in E:\Documentos(NO BORRAR)\Documentos de GonDC\Facu\SiGMA\asd - Copy\trunk\AccesoADatos\Datos.cs:14
   Herramientas.CargarCombos.cargarTipoDocumento(DropDownList& ddl) in E:\Documentos(NO BORRAR)\Documentos de GonDC\Facu\SiGMA\asd - Copy\trunk\Herramientas\CargarCombos.cs:30
   SiGMA._Default.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in E:\Documentos(NO BORRAR)\Documentos de GonDC\Facu\SiGMA\asd - Copy\trunk\SiGMA\RegistrarUsuario.aspx.cs:26
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +51
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +92
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +54
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +772
```

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace for the exception?

Comment: Can you post the code referenced here: AccesoADatos.SiGMAEntities..ctor(String connectionString, String asd) in E:\Documentos(NO BORRAR)\Documentos de GonDC\Facu\SiGMA\asd - Copy\trunk\AccesoADatos\DER.Designer.cs:79

Comment: Sorry, that stack trace was from a test that i did. The actual stack trace is posted now.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you dont have the right connectionString specified in your App.config or web.config. Make sure that the running applications App.config or web.config respectively contains the connectionString that you specified when defining the database model. Something like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="SiGMAEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/xxx.csdl|res://*/xxx.ssdl|res://*/xxx.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;xxx&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

xxx is just a placeholder for your stuff

Comment: No, i checked the connection strings like 10 times in the last couple of hours.

Comment: It is not about the string itself but whether it is placed in the right file (the app or web.config of the running assembly (not the one containing the db model)) and if it is named correctly. The name has to be the same as specified in the designer

Comment: It is placed everywhere(Web.config and the db model's project App.config)